# Transpose this easy equation please

Tags: linear-algebra

Hi guys i've got two questions which im struggling on.

Can you tranpose these two questions begginin with x please.

1.y = x/5 + 2x/3 + 4x/15

2. y = -5 + x/2

for question 1 I got x = y/(7+23) and for question 2 I got x=2y-10/2.  I'm not sure if these are correct though.

Comment: Can you tell us what you tried?

Comment: for question 1 I got x = y/(7+23) and for question 2 I got x=2y-10/2.  I'm not sure if these are correct though.

Comment: add the x terms then solve for x

Answer (score 1):

I think your answers are wrong. Use cross multiplication for the fractions in equation 1. Then both equations can be solved with simple manipulation (i.e multiplying through by denominators and adding and subtracting.) See what you get using this method.